# Error when loading JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I am facing a weird issue when rendering a JSP. I get the following error on load

```
Error:  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.setDisabled(Z)V
```

How to resolve this?

Edit: Below is the stack trace of the error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)

 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
```

JSP Code Snippet:

```
                            <td width="8%"><form:button
                                    id="id1"
                                    name="id1" disabled="true"
                                    class="idClass"
                                    onClick="operate()">Operate</form:button>
                            </td>
```

I have few code as mentioned above where i am disabling the buttons. Have javascript code to enable those on some conditions; like:

```
document.getElementById("id1").disabled = false;
```

Comment: Multiple jars on classpath ?

Comment: show us the jsp code.

Comment: no multiple jars in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample you have `<form:button>`. I guess *form* references the spring form taglib. But in the spring form taglib there is no *button* tag. Maybe you just should use a simple HTML button tag:

```
<button
   id="id1"
   name="id1" disabled="true"
   class="idClass"
   onClick="operate()">Operate</button>
```

Here is a link to the spring form taglib: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html